# JS mergeLinkedList misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, merge

As I recently began to code, I tried some LeetCode exercises and I ended up on the following one : I am supposed to merge sorted linked lists. After a few hours of struggle, I ended up looking for hints in users solutions and managed to adapt my code so it solves the problem. The problem is; I actually don't know why things work out and I feel like I miss something big.

In the following code, I don't get why operate on l (L) changes repList value; to me l = repList was just a value pass at time t.

```
/**
 * @param {ListNode} list1
 * @param {ListNode} list2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */



var mergeTwoLists = function (list1, list2) {
    if (list1 == null) return list2;
    if (list2 == null) return list1;

    let repList = new ListNode();
    let l = repList
    
    while(list1 != null || list2 != null){
        if ( list2 != null && list1 != null ){
            if (list1.val < list2.val){
                l.next = list1
                list1 = list1.next
            }else{
                l.next = list2
                list2 = list2.next
            }
        } 
        else {
            while(list1 != null){
                l.next = list1;list1 = list1.next;l = l.next
            }
            while(list2 != null){
                l.next = list2;list2 = list2.next;l = l.next
            }
        }
        l = l.next
    }
    
    return repList.next
};
```

`

The whole solution is based on this and I can't figure this out. I would love some help !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: that's because when you assign a variable value (repList) to another variable (L) it does not create a new object but rather assign a reference to that object to the variable (L). in this case both variables are referencing the same object (new ListNode()), so any change to that object will be reflected in each variable

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for the answer but im not sure to get it. I mean I get your explanations but when I tried what you told on a JS playground it didn't work. Maybe am I still missing the point ? Here is what I tried :
let message = new String()
let message2 = message 
message2 = "Modified"
console.log(message)
console.log(message2)
It should log 2 times modified ? Or am I wrong ?

Comment: It logs String{}
Modified

Comment: when you do `message2 = "Modified"` you don't modify the string object, you are assigning another string to the `message2` variable (ie, you replace the previous reference with another one) (btw, strings are immutable in js). Try it with an array and the results will be different. For ex.: `let a1 = [1,2] let a2 = a1 a2.push(3) print(a1) print(a2)`. You get `[1,2,3]` in both print calls

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I begin to get it but I still don't get when do you modify the object and when you just assign a new value, since the notations are pretty much the same a = b. Is it just type inherent (doesn't work on strings or ints but will on arrays) ? And what if I want to just pass the value without writing let a2 = [1,2] to not make it redundant? Thanks a whole lot for your time

Comment: `a = b` always means you are assigning. Are you modifying an object or replacing it depends on the assignment. For ex, `a.property = c` means you are modifying the object `a` by assigning to one of its property a new value. It does not replace the object, nor it creates a new one. Another example, `a.push()` is also modifying the object `a` by appending a new item to it. it is not so much type inherent. Taking my previous example, if instead of a2.push(3) I'll do a2 = [3], the a1 and a2 variables will behave independently giving [1,2] and [3] as print outputs.